# How to route packets from application to ip address

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, ip, routing

Is there a way to make an application send packets to different address than one it selects by default, Right now i disable all other network adapters then i start the application and then it chooses the one i want, I tried ForceBindIP but the application has protection against dll injection. So is there another way to do this?

Comment: Rin it from a vm with a real NIC assigned to the VM? Also, why are you trying this? Usually an application does not control this. The network stack does (OS wide), and there you can control your routing table.

Comment: @Hennes: Well, there are _quite a few_ apps which use `bind(3)` to choose the source address. Meanwhile, on both Windows and Linux the routing table only chooses the destination (although Linux has "policy routing" for selecting a preferred source).

Comment: @Hennes I need this for a game over openvpn.

Comment: @Hennes also , I can't use VM, just a batch script, because my friends need this too, and it would be too complicated to install vm's on their computers, i'm looking for a simpler solution, forcebindip is simple but unfortunately it doesn't work on this game , because it's protected by steam.

Comment: @grawity is there a way to set a default nic? So the game chooses that one.

Comment: Take a look at this. Note there are two different places that the priority is changed, the OP mentions one and the top answer has the other. Not sure if it will work for your situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785874/setting-network-adapter-metric-priority-in-windows-7